# Traverse records into columns for huge tables +800 million records

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2

How can I traverse records (actually a subset of columns) into one-record columns - up to 99 columns -- for a huge table?

I mean, I have a table with following sample structure/data :

```
TABLE_ORI
COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3 CODE VALUE
------- ------- ------- ---- ------------
C1      C2      C3      1    Value1
C1      C2      C3      2    Value2
C1      C2      C3      3    Value3
C100    C39     C21     1    Value40
C100    C39     C21     2    Value41
```

I want to convert this data into:

```
TABLE_NEW
COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3 VALUE1  VALUE2 VALUE3  VALUE4 VALUE5 ... VALUE99
------- ------- ------- ------  ------ ------- ------ ------     -------
C1      C2      C3      Value1  Value2 Value3
C100    C39     C21     Value40 Value41
```

Please consider this is a big table and result table can have up to 99 value columns. I tried a PL/SQL with nested loop besides bulk collect cursor but the process takes days and never ends.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you really only want 3 value columns in the pivoted result, or could there be more than this?

Comment: Indeed I have 99 possible values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would probably be the fastest way:

```
create table table_new as
select /*+ parallel */ column1, column2, column3,
    max(case when code = 1 then value else null end) value1,
    max(case when code = 2 then value else null end) value2,
    max(case when code = 3 then value else null end) value3,
    max(case when code = 4 then value else null end) value4,
    max(case when code = 5 then value else null end) value5,
    --...
    max(case when code = 99 then value else null end) value99
from table_ori
group by column1, column2, column3;
```

That assumes you have Enterprise Edition, a database that is configured to use parallelism properly, a large amount of tablespace to sort all the data at one time, etc.

It would also help performance to use the option `NOLOGGING` when creating the table.  That would avoid generating a lot of REDO and UNDO although at the expense of the table not being recoverable.

For large processes like this, Real-Time SQL Monitoring is the perfect way to diagnose problems.  If the above SQL is taking a long time, run a statement like this to monitor the SQL and see what operations and events are taking up the most time:

```
select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor('$the_real_sql_id') from dual;
```

Comment: Jon, all records will be selected. The final result is a new table